# cant find the O and the omega of the function (log n)!

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

[image]

i cant find the O and the Omega of the function (log n)! in the functions that are in the picture.
i tried to do : logn*(log n - 1)!< (log n)^n to find the O but it is dosent help me

Comment: What base do the `log`'s have in `f6`, `f7` and `f10`? These affect the order of growth.

Comment: f8=log(n)! mean (log n)! because there is also the function f5(5) that is log(n!).
the base is 2

Comment: Apologies, I saw `f5` immediately after I wrote that, so I deleted it. But `(log n)!` is non-reducible. (And the upper bound is `(log n)^(log n)` not `(log n)^n`). You might also want to consider changing the tags, e.g. `big-o` or `time-complexity` would be more relevant.

Comment: I don't know what you did but it is unlikely to be a useful reduction, unlike the case with `f5`.

Comment: i succeed to prove that f8=omega(f5) by this way:
(logn)!=log n(log -1)!>log n*2^(log n-1) (( because k!>2^k)) = log(n)(n/2)>c n*log n>c*c'*log(n!) But this trick dosent help me to find the O

Comment: That's what I meant: the O-notation is simply `O([log n]!)` because it is irreducible; and there is nothing wrong with writing something like `O(n!)` because it is an elementary function.